# Verifying ODBC connection to Informix in PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, informix

We've got a bit of a strange situation.    Had massive problems initially connecting to `Informix` via an `ODBC` data source using `PDO` and `PHP`.   Eventually worked out the connection string and it seemed to connect.    However, when I try to run any SQL against the database (using `prepare()` and `execute()` and even `PDO->query()` all I get returned is the value false.  No record set, no errors, no nothing.

If I change the data source name to something that doesn't exist I immediately get an error (that the data source doesn't exist) but as soon as the data source is correct the call to create a new `PDO` object runs.

I've wrapped my prepare and my query statements in a try/catch block and still nothing.

Can anyone give me any ideas on where we might be going wrong or more precisely how I can verify the connection to the database?  Even though there is no error I'm not convinced it's connected successfully.

The connection string is:

```
DSN=$database;UID=$username;PWD=$password;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Data source name not found, and no default driver specified' would came from the driver manager, so maybe, even when you specify a valid DSN, the driver may be failing to load (or not been there at all)

I suggest to make sure the ODBC driver is working using something like 'isql' (not sure what platform/driver manager you are using, but if is Linux, it should be UnixODBC which cames with 'isql' by default).
You may get a more meaningful error message from isql than php.

This is a quick connection using php and isql, check the env variables:

```
informix@irk:/usr3/products/php5$ echo $ODBCINI
/usr3/products/php5/odbc.ini

informix@irk:/usr3/products/php5$ echo $INFORMIXDIR
/usr3/products/4.10.UC7D

informix@irk:/usr3/products/php5$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr3/products/4.10.UC7D/lib:/usr3/products/4.10.UC7D/lib/cli:/usr3/products/4.10.UC7D/lib/esql

informix@irk:/usr3/products/php5$ cat $ODBCINI
[stores7]
Driver=/usr3/products/4.10.UC7D/lib/cli/iclit09b.so
Description=IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER
Database=stores7
LogonID=informix
pwd=dummy
Servername=irk1210
;
; UNICODE connection Section
;
[ODBC]
;uncomment the below line for UNICODE connection
;UNICODE=UCS-2
;UNICODE=UTF-8
;
; Trace file Section
;
Trace=0
TraceFile=/tmp/odbctrace2.out
InstallDir=/usr3/products/4.10.UC7D
TRACEDLL=idmrs09a.so

informix@irk:/usr3/products/php5$ grep irk1210 $INFORMIXSQLHOSTS
irk1210shm onipcshm irk irk1210shm
irk1210 onsoctcp irk  3046   

informix@irk:/usr3/products/php5$ cat t.php
<?php
try { 
 $db = new PDO("odbc:stores7", "informix", "dummy");
 print "Connection Established!\n"; 
 $result=$db->query("select tabname from systables;");
 $row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
 print_r($row);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
 print $e->getMessage();
} 
?>

informix@irk:/usr3/products/php5$ isql -v stores7
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> select first 1 tabname from systables
+---------------------------------------+
| tabname                                                                                                                         |
+---------------------------------------+
| systables                                                                                                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQLRowCount returns -1
1 rows fetched
SQL> ^C


informix@irk:/usr3/products/php5$ cat t.php
<?php
try { 
 $db = new PDO("odbc:stores7", "informix", "dummy");
 print "Connection Established!\n"; 
 $result=$db->query("select tabname from systables;");
 $row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
 print_r($row);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
 print $e->getMessage();
} 
?>

informix@irk:/usr3/products/php5$ php t.php
Connection Established!
Array
(
    [0] => systables
)
informix@irk:/usr3/products/php5$
```

Make sure you have the environment variable INFORMIXDIR pointing to CSDK, and LD_LIBRARY_PATH (again assuming this is Linux) set to at least:

```
$INFORMIXDIR/lib:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql:$INFORMIXDIR/cli
```

so the ODBC library can load all that it needs.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The client installed QTODBC and was able not only connect to the data source but also retrieve data.

We've re-tested, added a 30 second delay after the connection, jumped on to the Informix server and proven that there is a connection in place.

So basically we're back to square one.   It connects to the database but it doesn't matter how simplistic my SQL is, the query will run, no exceptions and no errors are generated but all that is returned is false.

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: the best way to know what's going on between client and server is get a SQLIDEBUG trace. If you set the environment variable 'SQLIDEBUG' to something like '2:/tmp/trace' (e.g. export SQLIDEBUG=2:/tmp/trace) and run whatever process that connects to the server, the informix libraries will dump every message between sever and client into the '/tmp/trace_xxx' file ('xxx' is based in the session number so it will vary). Then you can 'decode' the message with the sqliprint/sqliprt tool. You should be able to see all SQL stmts and the output from the server (returned data if any)

Answer (score 0):

Try my 2nd presentation from the IIUG 2017 conference:

http://smooth1.co.uk/ -> "IIUG 2017 conference Session A13/A14 Informix Application Development New Features - zip file 2"

Amongst the languages I cover Informix/PHP setup and usage.

Out of the zipfile

- php_htdocs.tar.gz Sample PHP files which can be dropped into an apache htdocs folder to test Informix/PHP.
- 201704_InfAppDev2.txt How to setup PHP/PDO/Informix and use the previous file.

As per below, the default error mode for PHP/PDO is PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT, you may want PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING or probably PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION exception based error handling.

My example htdocs include querying different ways, insert/update/delete, error handling and transaction processing.

```
<?php

$db = new PDO("informix:host=localhost.localdomain; service=23176;database=justdave; server=ol_informix1210; protocol=onsoctcp;EnableScrollableCursors=1;", "testuser", "testpass");
print "Connection Established!<br>";

# Default is PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT
print "<br><h2>PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT</h2><br>";
$db->query('SLECT name FROM test_table2');
print "PDO::errorCode ".$db->errorCode()."<br>";
print "PDO::errorInfo <br>";
$err=$db->errorInfo();
print_r($err);
print "<br><br>".$err[2]."<br>";

# Also PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING
print "<br><h2>PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING</h2><br>";
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$db->query('SLECT name FROM test_table2');

# Also PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
print "<br><h3>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION</h3><br>";
try {
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->query('SLECT name FROM test_table2');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error: ".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
        print "File: ".$e->getFile()."<br>";
        print "Line: ".$e->getLine()."<br>";
        print "Code: ".$e->getCode()."<br>";
        print "Trace: ";
        print_r($e->getTrace());
        print "<br><h2>Exception object</h2>";
        print_r($e);
        die();
}

?>
```